# RamdaJS is it overkill trying to point-free every function

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I recently got into functional programming bit by bit; started trying to point-free every function I code today.

I was practicing using Ramda while I was coding a **binary search algorithm**.

```
const R = require("ramda");

const getMidIndex = R.compose(
  R.call(R.invoker(1, "floor"), R.__, Math),
  R.divide(R.__, 2),
  R.apply(R.add),
  R.props(["upper", "lower"])
);

const getMidElement = R.converge(R.nth, [getMidIndex, R.prop("list")]);
const getSearchValue = R.prop("searchValue");

var binarySearch = R.compose(
  R.prop("ans"),
  R.until(
    R.either(
      R.compose(R.not, R.compose(R.isNil, R.prop("ans"))),
      R.compose(R.apply(R.gt), R.props(["lower", "upper"]))
    ),
    R.cond([
      [
        R.converge(R.equals, [getSearchValue, getMidElement]),
        R.converge(R.assoc("ans"), [getMidIndex, R.identity]),
      ],
      [
        R.converge(R.lt, [getSearchValue, getMidElement]),
        R.converge(R.assoc("upper"), [
          R.compose(R.dec, getMidIndex),
          R.identity,
        ]),
      ],
      [
        R.converge(R.gt, [getSearchValue, getMidElement]),
        R.converge(R.assoc("lower"), [
          R.compose(R.inc, getMidIndex),
          R.identity,
        ]),
      ],
    ])
  ),
  R.converge(R.assoc("upper"), [
    R.compose(R.dec, R.length, R.prop("list")),
    R.assoc("lower", 0),
  ]),
  R.assoc("ans", null),
  R.converge(R.mergeLeft, [
    R.compose(R.objOf("list"), R.nthArg(0)),
    R.compose(R.objOf("searchValue"), R.nthArg(1)),
  ])
);

var binarySearch = R.curryN(2, binarySearch);

module.exports = binarySearch;
```

the function takes two inputs a list and a value(v) -then-> the first three composing collecting args in an object like this

```
{
  searchValue: 7,
  list: [ 2, 3, 7, 12 ],
  ans: null,
  lower: 0,
  upper: 3
}
```

after finishing I started to wonder from the **performance** point of view *is this worse than having just one local midElement for example instead to keep calculating it*
am I on the right track or just wasting time is this even readable

Comment: "*Is it overkill trying to point-free every function*" - yes. There's a point where point-free becomes pointless.

Comment: "*Is this even readable?*" - no.

Comment: @Bergi thank you for your feedback, honestly, this's what I thought the only reason I started doing point-free everywhere I could is because I find it challenging and fun.
 Do you suggest that a function like should be written like a regular function and inside the body declare local variables and find where It fits more to use composition?

Comment: Yes, point-free is great fun, but even more so in a language like Haskell where it actually makes the code more concise :-) Yes, I definitely would recommend to write this `binarySearch` function using a `function` with parameters and variable declarations, especially for values that are used multiple times. Function compositions is useful where it removes deeply nested parentheses, or where temporary variables would have meaningless names anyway.

Comment: The fact that the code is point free is not the reason the code is unreadable. You have a number of 'expressions' that are repeated here and should be given proper names. e.g. `R.converge(COMPARE_FN, [getSearchValue, getMidElement])` and `R.converge(R.assoc(LABEL), [R.compose(ORDER, getMidIndex),R.identity]),`

Comment: The only reason `converge` was added to Ramda was to make it easier to write point-free code.  I'm one of the Ramda authors, and have regretted that function pretty much ever since I wrote it.  It makes it possible to write code like this... which is to my mind, *always* a bad idea.  Point-free coding is a tool.  Use it if it makes your code easier to understand.  Skip it if it doesn't.  Here it definitely doesn't, although you might still follow Chad's advice and break out useful functions.  With enough of them, perhaps point-free would again be reasonable.

Comment: Just compare your `getMidIndex` with `const getMidIndex = ({upper, lower}) => Math .floor ((upper + lower) / 2)`, and it's clear that point-free is not always a win!